# Line of code that simulates/emulates keyboard press for windows xp/vista/7/8 from .php

Tags: javascript, php, windows, hotkeys

**How do I emulate a keyboard key press for windows environment** (not for browser) **from a .php file with javascript**?

---

**How to connect PHP to Local pc through HotKeys?**

I have an automated bot that runs on a local windows machine that calculates and returns a result for other user. The bot program needs a Hot-key keyboard key press (any that I define) to run.

**User actions:**
User will request a calculation and it will be stored in Mysql database.

**Local machine Web Browser:**
I will be running a continual forever loop checking the Mysql for changes like a simple **IF statement: `colomn_A == defined`** and **`column_b is undefined`** then **run script**

**Local machine HotKey activated Bot:**
The script will initiate local machine to calculate and return a value to `column_b` which will close restart the .php.

**User actions:**
User can will refresh screen and see requested information added to the public list.

---

My concern using exec is the direct connection to my local machine and possibly my entire network. This solution would provide me mobility without any new coding to my-site. I am just needing the line of code to simulate the key press.

**If people have issues with this is there a program that will watch a remote mysql database and simulate a keypress of the desired hotkey that initiates the program and supplies the data visually onscreen?**

Comment: You can simulate a key press in JavaScript (more easily in JQuery) for web browsers, if that's what you're looking for.  If not, your JavaScript tag is not helpful.

Comment: Totally, agree I found plenty on jquery and looks like I am heading that direction but was hoping for a software program that can handle it.  I most likely will alter the code to my current program to do this functionality but I am trying not to recreate the wheel.

Comment: Why *software program*?  Seems overcomplicated if you're using PHP and JavaScript.  The browser is listening for keys.  If you don't like the JavaScript interface for that, then create your own software program or search for one on Google.  I, however, would never trust such a program.  I would construct it myself and program it in C++, Java, or C#, not PHP and JavaScript.

Comment: That is the problem the browser is listening to keys I am looking into AutoHotKey. Seems like it will do what I need with lots of programming. WANT program because I like to look at the features and get an idea of what I want/need before I start programming a function, because what I an envisioning may be way off of what is needed.